# how to fetch a range of files from an FTP server using C#

Tags: c#, ftp, wildcard

i'm stuck at a point where i am using a wildcard parameter with the FtpWebRequest object as suck

```
   FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + WildCard));
```

now this works fine, however i now want to fetch a specific range of files.

say the file naming structure is `*YYYYMMDD.*` and i need to fetch all the files prior to today's date.

i've been searching for a wildcard pattern for that with no good results, one that will work in a simple file listing.

and it doesn't look like i can use regex here.

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FTP `RETR` (retrieve) command does not support wild cards.

You will have to get a `LIST` of all files, loop over them and retrieve only the ones that follow the pattern you need.

[RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) does not specify wild cards, but simply states a `<pathname>` should be passed to the `RETR` command.

Comment: i'm aware of that part, that's why i'm specifying the wildcard pattern in the file listing params. so when i do get a list of all files they will be all the files specified by the wildcard provided